# Literary device for sound ending similar to the next word's beginning

Tags: phrase-request, terminology

What literary device is it if a word begins with the sound the previous word ends in?
such as 'doubt' and 'truth' in: Doubt truth to be a liar.

Comment: Don't know any literary device but it's *gemination*.

Comment: This is a literary device, and so this question would have worked better on [english.se] or [literature.se]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [consonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_consonance). It is the consonant version of assonance, and alliteration is a more specific type of consonance.

---

However, I do not think I would characterize the end of "doubt" as having the same sound as the beginning of "truth".

Comment: It is not specific to the end of one  word and the beginning of another, but could work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that your example matches your question as you stated it.

Nevertheless, in English, when one word (or first part of compound word) ends with a phonetic sound, and the next word (or second part of a compound word) begins with the same phonetic sound, it's called **gemination**.

Examples:

- life force

  lampost

  fish shop

  cattail

  misspell